# swift: how can I delete a specific character?

Tags: swift, string, swift2

a string such as `!   !! yuahl! !` , I want delete `!` and  , when I code like this

```
for index in InputName.characters.indices {
    if String(InputName[index]) == "" || InputName.substringToIndex(index) == "!" {
        InputName.removeAtIndex(index)
    }
}
```

have this error " fatal error: subscript: subRange extends past String end ", how should I do? THX :D

Comment: (The error probably comes from doing the remove inside the loop. After the first removal, your risk running off the end of the String.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need to remove characters only on both ends, you can use `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(_:)`

```
let delCharSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "! ")

let s1 = "! aString! !"
let s1Del = s1.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(delCharSet)
print(s1Del) //->aString

let s2 = "! anotherString !! aString! !"
let s2Del = s2.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(delCharSet)
print(s2Del) //->anotherString !! aString
```

If you need to remove characters also in the middle, "reconstruct from the filtered output" would be a little bit more efficient than repeating single character removal.

```
var tempUSView = String.UnicodeScalarView()
tempUSView.appendContentsOf(s2.unicodeScalars.lazy.filter{!delCharSet.longCharacterIsMember($0.value)})
let s2DelAll = String(tempUSView)
print(s2DelAll) //->anotherStringaString
```

If you don't mind generating many intermediate Strings and Arrays, this single liner can generate the expected output:

```
let s2DelAll2 = s2.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(delCharSet).joinWithSeparator("")
print(s2DelAll2) //->anotherStringaString
```

Comment: Don't forget that you need to `import Foundation` for this code to work.

Answer (score 25):

**Swift 5+**

```
let myString = "aaaaaaaabbbb"
let replaced = myString.replacingOccurrences(of: "bbbb", with: "") // "aaaaaaaa"
```

Answer (score 5):

I find that the `filter` method is a good way to go for this sort of thing:

```
let unfiltered = "!   !! yuahl! !"

// Array of Characters to remove
let removal: [Character] = ["!"," "]

// turn the string into an Array
let unfilteredCharacters = unfiltered.characters

// return an Array without the removal Characters
let filteredCharacters = unfilteredCharacters.filter { !removal.contains($0) }

// build a String with the filtered Array
let filtered = String(filteredCharacters)

print(filtered) // => "yeah"

// combined to a single line
print(String(unfiltered.characters.filter { !removal.contains($0) })) // => "yuahl"
```

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 3**

In Swift 3, the syntax is a bit nicer. As a result of the Great Swiftification of the old APIs, the factory method is now called `trimmingCharacters(in:)`. Also, you can construct the `CharacterSet` as a `Set` of single-character `String`s:

```
let string = "!   !! yuahl! !"
string.trimmingCharacters(in: [" ", "!"]) // "yuahl"
```

If you have characters in the middle of the string you would like to remove as well, you can use `components(separatedBy:).joined()`:

```
let string = "!   !! yu !ahl! !"
string.components(separatedBy: ["!", " "]).joined() // "yuahl"
```

H/T @OOPer for the Swift 2 version

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> func trimLast(character chars: Set<Character>) -> String {
>     
>     let str: String = String(self.reversed())
>
>     guard let index = str.index(where: {!chars.contains($0)}) else {
>         return self
>     }
>     return String((str[index..<str.endIndex]).reversed())
> }
> ```

Note:
By adding this function in `String` extension, you can delete the specific character of string at last.

Answer (score 0):

```
for index in InputName.characters.indices.reversed() {
    if String(InputName[index]) == "" || InputName.substringToIndex(index) == "!" {
        InputName.removeAtIndex(index)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can add such very helpful extension :

```
import Foundation


extension String{
 func exclude(find:String) -> String {
    return stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(find, withString: "", options: .CaseInsensitiveSearch, range: nil)
 }
 func replaceAll(find:String, with:String) -> String {
    return stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(find, withString: with, options: .CaseInsensitiveSearch, range: nil)
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

for example if you want to remove "%" the percent from 10%

```
 if let i = text.firstIndex(of: "%") {
        text.remove(at: i) //10
    }
```